# MouseOver of FlexTable with GWT

Tags: java, gwt, widget, mouseevent, mouseover

Hello everyone
I have a FlexTable that contains images (one for each cell). I wish I had an event that you move your mouse over the cell comes out a popup that should contain the title of the image.
Someone can give me a hand?

I tried to insert this code does what he must do (at least for me) but the popup remains active when I remove the mouse pointer .where I wrong?

```
private FlexTable createHTML(ImageResult result,int row,final int i,int currentCol) {

 immagine[i]=new Image(result.getThumbnailUrl());
 resultsTableImm.setWidget(row, currentCol, immagine[i]);
 titleImm[i]=result.getTitleNoFormatting();
 contentImm[i]=result.getContentNoFormatting();
 urlImm[i]=result.getUnescapedUrl();

 immagine[i].addMouseOverHandler(new MouseOverHandler() {

       @Override
        public void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent event) {

            PopupPanel p = new PopupPanel(true);
            Widget source = (Widget) event.getSource();
            int x = source.getAbsoluteLeft() + 10;
            int y = source.getAbsoluteTop() + 10;
            p.add(new HTML("<b>"+titleImm[i]+"</b><br>"+contentImm[i])); 
            p.setPopupPosition(x, y);
        p.show();
        }
    });

    return resultsTableImm;
            }
```

Thank you and have a nice day

JD

Comment: How are you adding the images to the FlexTable? Some code would be nice.

Comment: I'm inserting images using the Google Search API classes (if I find a result the image inserted into a table). At the moment I have a table with all the images downloaded from Google's servers (it's a 4x8). I wish that when I pass the mouse over an image will open a popup that tells me the title and the url of the latter (a bit like GoogleImage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FlexTable hasn't `onMouseOverHandler`. It only has `clickHandler`. So you can't attach mouse over handler to the table(cell). One way is addMouseOverHandler to the image show them in the popuplike that

```
Image image= new Image();
image.addMouseOverHandler(new MouseOverHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent event) {
            PopupPanel p = new PopupPanel(true);
            Widget source = (Widget) event.getSource();
            int x = source.getAbsoluteLeft() + 10;
            int y = source.getAbsoluteTop() + 10;

            p.add(image); 
            p.setPopupPosition(x, y);
            p.show();
        }
    });
```

If you use gwt2.1 then I suggest you to use [CellTable](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/google/gwt/gwt-dev/2.1.0/gwt-dev-2.1.0-javadoc.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTable.html)

Look at this example [Cell Table](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable)

Comment: ok, perfect. now I have to try to figure out how to convert my FlexTables in CellTable ..

Comment: ouch..objects CellTable haven't method setHTML() ... I need it to insert the image ...

Comment: look at this sample http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellSampler and image at each row

Comment: Yes, but I have to get an image from a url that I get it from an object of type ImageResult ... with the Flextable object I can use the method .setHTML(row,col,"<a href....>)

Comment: If I insert images into an array of type Image, and I place them in FlexTable (I test it,and I can do this). how do I must do to handle an event MO on I-th image? Thanks a lot again ..

Comment: you should keep their image and addHandler to them

Comment: If I keep them in an array of 32 cells (number of image). Then Can I  do a loop  where for each image into array, I add a popup?

Answer (score 0):

You can make custom widget with registered onmouseover handler and place it to flex table (idea is not trying to add listener for cell, but have it on widget itself which resides in cell).

Or you can try something like this:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/GWT/TableMouseOverEvent.htm

Answer (score 0):

Boiling down Xorty's example to the essentials of the present question you may adapt the following extension of FlexTable:

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Element;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Event;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlexTable;

public class PTable extends FlexTable {

    public static final String ROW_STYLE_NAME  = "pm-PTable-row";

    PTable() {
        setStyleName("pm-PTable");
        sinkEvents(Event.ONMOUSEOVER |Event.ONMOUSEOUT); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
        super.onBrowserEvent(event);
        Element td = getEventTargetCell(event);
        if (td == null) return;
        Element tr = DOM.getParent(td);
        switch (DOM.eventGetType(event)) {
            case Event.ONMOUSEOVER: {
                tr.addClassName(ROW_STYLE_NAME + "-mouseover");
                break;
            }
            case Event.ONMOUSEOUT: {
                tr.removeClassName(ROW_STYLE_NAME + "-mouseover");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```